# Missing Environment Vars in docker python:3 with docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, django-migrations

Though my configuration looks good, my `python:3` image does not seem to have the expected `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` set, at least at the point that the `Dockerfile` attempts to run migrations

```
$ docker-compose config
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: /Users/ben/Projects/falcon/falcon-backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
    environment:
      DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: 'some-secret-that-works-elsewhere'
$
$ docker-compose up --build api
[...]
 Step 6/7 : RUN echo `$DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`
 ---> Running in fbfb569c0191

[...]
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DJANGO_SECRET_KEY env variable
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py migrate' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

however, the final line, 
`CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001 --settings=falcon.settings.dev-microservice` does start up as desired, with the necessary env vars set.

```
# Dockerfile -- api

FROM python:3

RUN pip3 -q install -r requirements.txt
RUN echo `$DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`
RUN python manage.py migrate --settings=falcon.settings.dev-microservice # <-- why does this not work
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001 --settings=falcon.settings.dev-microservice
```

Why does the penultimate line of the `Dockerfile` fail due to an unset environment variable while the final one works as expected?

Comment: why do you run `migrate` when building image? you should run it before starting the runserver (in the same `CMD` not in seperate RUN

Comment: the reason is that I am inexperienced in these matters, so the distinction between the the RUN step as building the image vs. a CMD starting up the application was less clear than it is now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RUN` is used only when building image. The `CMD` is the command that is started when you start container from your image. If you run migrate when building image it is wrong, migrate is building your database and you want to run it each time before runserver

```
# Dockerfile -- api

FROM python:3

RUN pip3 -q install -r requirements.txt
RUN echo `$DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`
CMD /bin/bash -c "python manage.py migrate --settings=falcon.settings.dev-microservice && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001 --settings=falcon.settings.dev-microservice"
```

**This is the proper way how to start django in docker, because you want to run the migrations on production when starting server. Not on your PC when building image...**

Answer (score 5):

The environment variables **not declared inside the Dockerfile** are not visible to the container when building the image. They are only passed to the container at runtime. Since the `RUN` instruction executes on build, the environment variable `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY` which is declared outside the Dockerfile won't be visible to the `RUN` command.

To solve the issue you can declare the env variable inside the Dockerfile and set it via a build argument:

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip3 -q install -r requirements.txt
ARG key
ENV DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=$key
RUN echo `$DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`
RUN python manage.py migrate --settings=falcon.settings.dev-microservice
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001 --settings=falcon.settings.dev-microservice
```

Then, you should modify the composefile as such:

```
build:
  context: /Users/ben/Projects/falcon/falcon-backend
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  args:
    - key='secrete-key'
```

Comment: This explains why the secret key is not available in the run command. However, as Mazel Tov says in the comments, it’s a strange decision to run migrate as a `RUN`, command, so changing the Dockerfile in this way is probably not the best solution.